# Show previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button

How to remove current and show previous fragment? Like if I'm press "Back" button

I'm using such construction:

```
FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
ft.remove(fragment).commit();
```

But it just removes current fragment, without showing previous

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to call [`FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29) where you add the fragment and then call [`FragmentManager.popBackStack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28%29) when you want to remove it.

Comment: And if you do this, you won't have to override the BACK button behavior. The visible fragment will automatically be removed and the next fragment in the backstack will be shown automatically when you hit BACK.

Comment: FragmentManager.popBackStack()  reloading the fragment.

Answer (score 4):

Add this method in your activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            if( this.getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0 ){
                this.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                return true;
            }
            // If there are no fragments on stack perform the original back button event
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Then where you are changing the fragments do this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new YourFragmentName());
transaction.addToBackStack(null); // this is needed for the above code to work
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to show previous fragment after remove:

```
  FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.remove(fragment).commit();

  previousFragment=(SherlockFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentByTag(""+currentTagNum);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .show(mFragment)
            .commit();
```